# Display data on searching an empty string in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 handleChange(e, isEnter) {
  const searchData = () => {
  let tempMenuProductDetails = this.props.menu_items;
  if (this.state.searchString == null) {
    this.setState({
      displayItems: tempMenuProductDetails
    }, function () {
      console.log(this.state.displayItems);
    })
  }
  const filterArray = tempMenuProductDetails.reduce((result, category) => {
    if (category.categoryName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.searchString.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
      result.push(category);
    }
    if (category.productList && category.productList.length > 0) {
      category.productList = category.productList.reduce((productListResult, productList) => {
        if (!!productList.productName && productList.productName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.searchString.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
          productListResult.push(productList);
        }
        return productListResult;
      }, []);
    }
    if (category.productList.length) {
      result.push(category);
    }
    return result;
  }, []);
  this.setState({
    displayItems: filterArray
  }, function () {
    console.log(this.state.displayItems);
  })
}
if (!isEnter) {
  this.setState({
    searchString: e.target.value
  });
} else {
  searchData();
}
}

search(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
  this.handleChange(e, true);
 }
  this.handleChange(e, false);
 }

 render() {
   return (
      <FormControl value={this.state.searchString} type="text" 
         placeholder="Search Items"
         className="search" onChange={this.handleChange} onKeyDown=
       {this.search} />
      )
   }
```

---

The problem with this search function is that it gives the duplicate data when searched and does not re-render the original data when someone searches nothing in the input box instead just presses enter.

For ex- If I search "chicken" and press enter ,it displays correct data twice. Then I delete chicken and press enter with nothing typed in the search box ,it does not re-render the original data. How do I fix this?

It only re-renders the original data when the page is refreshed. And it works fine if I remove the  "if (this.state.searchString == null)"  part of code.

Thanks in advance.
[I searched fries and pressed enter,it shows fries.Then I clear searchbox and press enter,it shows two fries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZBsq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update **if** condition to check for **falsy** value i.e. both null and empty string. When you delete "Chicken" after searching for "Chicken", **state** object is not null rather its empty string with zero length **""**. Hence we have to check for length.

Its a good approach to check for **falsy** value like

```
  if (!this.state.searchString) {
    this.setState({
      displayItems: tempMenuProductDetails
    }, function () {
      console.log(this.state.displayItems);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Basically what your answer does is it works correct on my one component but does not work on the other.

Comment: on the other component when i clear the search box and press enter, it renders the data twice. I am adding the screenshot in the question.

Comment: I think issue here is with the logic that has been implement. Would recommend to check with this implementation for a string search on JSON data.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/imsontosh/jky7L6r5/)